# C# emgucv - Point value (X, Y)

Tags: c#, emgucv

What I'm trying to do basically is a "color tracker" tool, that's supposed to get the coordinates of the objects after filtering them with a list of minimum/maximum RGB values using the code below:

```
Rgb lowerLimit = new Rgb(235, 8, 25);
Rgb upperLimit = new Rgb(255, 20, 40);

Image<Gray, byte> imageHSVDest = _img.InRange(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
imageBox1.Image = imageHSVDest;
```

However, since multiple objects will be filtered (keep in mind that the objects will be "next together" as in still horizontally and vertically, just different position on screen every time) I would like to calculate the distance from the first object to the last one (they're basically a semi-rectangular objects).

Here's the picture I'm talking about:
[image: Pic]

First time asking a question here, so excuse me if I made any mistake here or wasn't being clear.